# ExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js

On Ubuntu 16.04 with Ruby 2.3.3, Rails 5.0.0.1, and NodeJS 4.2.6 installed, I generated a toy controller with `bin/rails generate controller welcome index`. After running `bin/rails server`, I opened `http://localhost:3000/welcome/index` in my browser to get the following error:

```
ExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#index

Showing /rails-app-path/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #7 raised:

ReferenceError: CoffeeScript is not defined

Extracted source (around line #7):


    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172243/reference-error-coffeescript-is-not-defined/41173000#41173000)

There is a problem in coffe-script-source gem 1.12.1 which was recently updated. the issue is that the source file in this version is empty. there is already an [open issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/4403) , and it should be fixed soon.

For now you can add this to your GemFile

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '= 1.11.1'
```

and run `bundle update coffee-script-source` until it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, a broken version 1.12.1 of the `coffee-script-source` gem had been uploaded. That version has now been [unpublished](https://rubygems.org/gems/coffee-script-source/), so the above hello world app now works (once I rebundled my gems).

Answer (score 0):

ExecJS::ProgramError in Welcome#index error :

It's an easy fix you just have to rename a file,
app/views/layouts/**application**.html.erb

TO

app/views/layouts/**default**.html.erb

And then the magic happens :)